# How to test arguments for a figure or axis object in MATLAB 2022?

Tags: matlab, testing, arguments, matlab-figure

A function receives a figure or axis object object as parameter.
I want to test this as shown in the `FIXME` line.
Which test should be used here in order to allow all valid objects for `exportgraphics`?

```
% myexportgraphics.m
function myexportgraphics(f)
arguments
  f (1,1) {}; % FIXME add a test here 
end

exportgraphics(f,...);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This full list of validation functions is documented here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/argument-validation-functions.html

The only relevant one for checking the input type (other than ones for specific types like "double") is [`mustBeUnderlyingType`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mustbeunderlyingtype.html)

You can check which types are valid using `underlyingType` on example objects you want to accept.

```
underlyingType( figure() );  % 'matlab.ui.Figure'
underlyingType( axes() );    % 'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes'
```

So this would check for figures

```
function myexportgraphics(f)
arguments
  f (1,1) {mustBeUnderlyingType(f,'matlab.ui.Figure')};  
end

end
```

However, that doesn't allow multiple variable types, so per the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/argument-validation-functions.html) you probably want to make your own validation function

```
function myexportgraphics(f)
arguments
  f (1,1) {mustBeExportGraphicsType(f)}; 
end

end

function mustBeExportGraphicsType(g)
    if ~ismember( class(g), {'matlab.ui.Figure','matlab.graphics.axis.Axes'} )
        eidType = 'mustBeExportGraphicsType:notExportGraphicsType';
        msgType = 'Input must be a figure or axes object';
        throwAsCaller(MException(eidType,msgType));
    end
end
```

These are the requirements for a custom validation function, emphasis mine:

> Functions used for validation have these design elements:
>
> - Validation functions do not return outputs or modify program state. The only purpose is to check the validity of the input value.
> - Validation functions must accept the value being validated as an input argument. If the function accepts more than one input argument, the first input is the value to be validated.
> - Validation functions rely only on the inputs. No other values are available to the function.
> - Validation functions throw an error if the validation fails. Using throwAsCaller to throw exceptions avoids showing the validation function itself in the displayed error message.
>
> **Creating your own validation function is useful when you want to provide specific validation that is not available using the MATLAB validation functions**. You can create a validation function as a local function within the function file or place it on the MATLAB path.

---

As an aside, you could use `ishghandle` within the custom validation function which returns true for figure and axes inputs. If you didn't use the `arguments` validation syntax, you could instead use `ishghandle` with the slightly older `inputParser` approach to input validation, or a simple `assert` near the start of your function, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question.